# Reverse audio file (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, file, buffer, reverse

How, using node js platform, reverse (playback version of file) audio file? And how it actually works ?
I already tried to reverse buffer of file:

```
let fs = require('fs');
var buffertools = require('buffertools');
let reverse = require("buffer-reverse")

let data =  fs.readFileSync('./test.mp3');

fs.writeFileSync('resulty.mp3',new Buffer(buffertools.reverse(data)));
```

Comment: you think that reversing the audio buffer should play the song in reverse?

Comment: I don't know how it actually must work.Thus why I ask question

Answer (score 0):

You can use fluent-FFMPEG:

```
// with Audio file on server via fs
ffmpeg
        .input("cdn/" + jobID + "_tmp.mp3")
        .outputOptions(["-c copy", "-af areverse"])
        .save("cdn/" + jobID + "mp3");
```